# How to call StoredProcedure in SQL server from C++ code?

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-c++

I have a project of C++ windows form. Now, I want to call StoredProcedure in SQL server database. 
How can I call storedProcedure from C++ code?

Here is my code.
It shows me an error in 
`com->CommandType = CommandType->StoredProcedure`
It gives an error that `Type name is not allowed`

```
    con->ConnectionString = "Data Source=122.179.140. 225\\EIEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ICAST_IMS;Uid=developer;pwd=developer@12345";
    con->Open();

    SqlCommand^ com = gcnew SqlCommand();
    com->Connection = con;
    //com->CommandText = "Update ProductionBatch set NoduleCount=@final_nodule_count ,nodularity=@final_nodularity, ferrite=@final_ferrite, perlite=@final_perlite where batchid=@batchid;";
    com->CommandText = "UpdateMicroFromImageProccesing";
    com->CommandType = CommandType->StoredProcedure;
    com->Parameters->AddWithValue("@final_nodularity", round1(final_nodularity));
    com->Parameters->AddWithValue("@final_nodule_count", final_nodule_count);
    com->Parameters->AddWithValue("@final_ferrite", round1(final_ferrite));
    com->Parameters->AddWithValue("@final_perlite", round1(final_perlite));
    com->Parameters->AddWithValue("@batchid", (heatBox->SelectedValue->ToString()));
    com->ExecuteNonQuery();
    com->Parameters->Clear();
    con->Close();
```

I included

```
    using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::Sql;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;
using namespace System::Data::SqlTypes;
using namespace Microsoft::SqlServer::Server;
```

Comment: Don't know if that's your issue, but your code there actually says `StoreProcedure` - note the missing `d`.

Comment: Sorry, It was my typo mistake. 
But an error is still coming after correcting the spelling.

Comment: don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Try it [this way](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp.net/Database-ADO.net/useSqlCommandtocallstoredprocedure.htm)